# Opening .pdf with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have code below, it seems to not be opening the pdf please help. I am very fluent with VBA but not with vba object orientated code with adobe.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub SeperatePDFFile()

Dim selectpdf As String
Dim caption As String
Dim filter As String
Dim gApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim gPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set gPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

caption = "Please Select an input file must extension .pdf"
selectpdf = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

gPDDoc.Open (selectpdf)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is not working?  Is there error message? did you include all the library required?

Comment: Yes I added the Adobe 10.0 reference library and there is no error message the program runs to the end with nothing happening.

Comment: hm maybe there are some errors that is not caught?  Try throw in an On error goto err and see if that gives you anything?  You can remove the on error line after

Comment: I ran the error handler and nothing came up Ill take a look deeper into the code this week and see if anything comes up.

Comment: I see.  My suggestion for next step is to  copy & paste code to a new sub and change it to open a random excel workbook instead.  If it fails the same way then the error might lies with activex.  Otherwise my guess will be the Acrobat

Comment: Alex thanks for the help I will look into that, just as a quick lookover does the syntax of the code above look correct to you would you think that this code should work at first glance?

Comment: I haven't verify the code but it looks correct to me.  However there are a few possibilities that it won't work.  E.g. access right (if the pdf is open from network), your adobe reader, filepath in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to open the PDF, is there any reason to automate Acrobat rather thank just using ShellExecute (which'd open pretty much any file that's registered in windows)?

```
Option Explicit

    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Sub Test()

        If LaunchFile("C:\temp\somefile.pdf") > 32 Then
            ' it worked, the file's open
        Else
            ' failed for some reason
        End If

    End Sub

    Function LaunchFile(sFileName As String) As Long
    ' Requires the full path to the file to be launched

        LaunchFile = ShellExecute(0&, vbNullString, sFileName, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus)

    End Function
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is build a program that exports text to excel from a pdf and then use this text to separate and extract pages based of the content of a pdf. I am just trying to get started with this code.

Comment: Then my reply won't help.  Sorry.